# How to fix Not Found [CFN #0005] error

Tags: laravel, web-hosting

I have uploaded the Laravel5 project live,homepage loads fine,but when I try to open any other link I get this `Not Found [CFN #0005]` error. How to fix that?

Here is .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you add the content of your `.htaccess` in the question?

Comment: Just as @RonvanderHeijden just mentioned, check your `.htaccess` or you don't have it at all in your folder.

Comment: I have .htaccess file,please view my updated question